# Get an array of matches in string as indexes

Tags: javascript, string, arraylist, string-matching

Example: "abc abc ab a".indexOfList("abc") returns [0,4]

My code:

```
String.prototype.indexOfList=function(word){
    var l=[];
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){ //For each character
        var pushed=(this[i]==word[0])&&(word.length+i<=this.length);
        if (pushed) {
            for(var j=1;j<word.length;j++){
                if (word[j]!=this[i+j]) {
                    pushed=false; break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (pushed) {
            l.push(i);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

Is there a better and smaller way than this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `match` command:

```
var re = /abc/g,
str = "abc abc ab a";

var pos = [];
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    pos.push(match.index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a version that could handle overlapping strings, i.e. pattern `aaa` for a string `aaaaa` should return `[0,1,2]`.

```
function indexOfList(needle, haystack) {
  const result = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (haystack.includes(needle, i)) {
    const match = haystack.indexOf(needle, i);
    result.push(match);
    i = match + 1;
  }
  return result;
}

indexOfList("abc", "abc abc ab a"), // [0, 4]
indexOfList("aaa", "aaaabc abc ab a") // [0, 1]
```

I would also advice against extending the prototype of a native object. It could lead to a very nasty name clashes.

Consider your collegue (or even a language maintainer) adds a function with the same name.

Comment: I was thinking about this method but cutting off with substring for each found word.

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate things. A very similar method to this already exists: [String.indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

You can also pass a second parameter to this method, telling it where to start looking. If you keep increasing this second parameter, you can quickly find each occurrence.

```
String.prototype.indexOfList = function(word) {
    var start = this.indexOf(word);
    var l = [start]

    if(start == -1) {
        return [-1, -1];
    }

    var index = start;
    for(var i = start + word.length; i < this.length - word.length; i = index) {
        index = this.indexOf(word, i);

        if(index == -1) {
            break;
        }

        l.push(index);
    }

    return l;
}
```

This will start at the first occurrence, and continue to add on each index the word appears at.

Comment: your method returns the start and end indexes. he wants the start index of each match in the string.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes I see. I misunderstood the question, edited now.

Answer (score 0):

With `indexOf` function

```js
var str = "abc abc ab a";
var i = -1;
var result = [];

while (true) {
    i = str.indexOf("abc", i + 1);
    if (i == -1) break;
    result.push(i);
}

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace`

```js
String.prototype.indexOfList = function(word){
    var l=[];
    this.replace(new RegExp(word,"g"), (a,i) => l.push(i));
    return l;
}

console.log("abc abc ab a".indexOfList("abc"));
```